# Отсутствует таблица в SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: RESUME (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM RESUME

Потому что в предыдущей версии этой таблицы "RESUME" не было. Щас добавил и запустил и получил эту ошибку.

Как исправить эту ошибку *(кроме удаления приложения и заново запустить или очистки кэша)*?

Comment: База данных и таблицы создаются в какой момент?

Comment: База создается в Первом Activity, а эта таблица во Втором Activity? после создания базы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему никто не читает документацию? Создайте дополнительную таблицу в методе [SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)).

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL("create table resume ...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Может потому, что с английским не дружат? не?

Comment: @TITAN С английским желательно подружиться, если живете программированием.

Comment: Конечно. Так, каждый раз вызывать onUpgrade перед новой таблицей, а старые данные в базе не удалятся?

Comment: Есть книги, статьи и инструкции на русском.

Comment: `onUpgrade` вызывается сама, когда изменяется версия базы. Остаётся только для каждой версии выполнить свои инструкции. Если это не `DROP` или `DELETE`, данные никуда не денутся.